# Create a column that is the sum of # previous column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe structured in this way:

```
###Date, A, B###
2020.06.10, 2, 3
```

I need to create an additional column which sum the previous two column using the index (without df['A'] or df['B']).

```
###Date, A, B, C###
2020.06.10, 2, 3, 5
```

Thank you in advance!

Paolo

Comment: Is `Date` the index or another column? Are there more columns?

Answer (score 1):

```py
n_previous = 2
df["another"] = df.iloc[:,-n_previous:].sum(axis=1)
```

Take n previous columns and sum along the row axis

Answer (score 0):

```
df["new"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[-2] + x[-1], axis=1)
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not infer the last 2 columns from `df.columns`?:

```
cols = df.columns[-2:]
df['new'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.iloc` and slice all rows and get the `nth` column through to `nth+2` column
Where

```
n=starting column, integer index
n+2=ending column, integer index
```

**Explanation**; `df.iloc[:,nth:nth+2` works like a python range, the ending number in the column range selection is not inclusive in the selection

In your case

```
n=1#starting column index
df['c']=df.iloc[:,n:n+2].apply(lambda x: x.sum(), axis=1)

Date           A    B   c
0   2020.06.10  2   3   5
```